# how can I configure my app to only accept connections from three explicitly-specified clients?

Tags: django, django-1.7

So I have a Django app that serves as the backend for another app that I've written.  I only want my Django app to be accessed from this other app, which will probably have a handful of versions (production, staging, dev1, dev2).  How can I configure my Django app to only accept connections from these handful of clients?

Comment: Can you give some more details on how the Django app will receive connections from the other app? Are they HTTP posts or something like that?

Comment: Yes, just a REST API - GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, with token authentication.

Comment: You can do it with apache like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145978/only-allow-certain-ip-addresses-to-access-site-with-mod-rewrite

Comment: Are these apps on a controlled network or remote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you well you want to control the access to your Django App, one option is to add a custom Middleware to check the IP of the user and if it's not allowed you can show an error, or redirect to other site or whatever you want.

```
class CheckIPMiddleware(object):
    # Check if client IP is allowed
    def process_request(self, request):
        allowed_ips = ['192.168.1.1', '123.123.123.123', etc...]
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')  # Get client IP
        if ip not in allowed_ips:
           # Here you can raise a 403 Forbidden
           # or redirect to any other site/page

        # If user is allowed nothing happens
        return None
```

If this is useful to you you have to remember 2 things:

- Add code to a file following this path: `your_project/middleware/checkipmiddleware.py`
- Edit your settings and add `your_project_name.middleware.checkipmiddleware.CheckIPMiddleware` into your middleware *( look for `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (...` in your settings.py )*