# hw to redirect one website to another website in cpanel

Tags: web, cpanel, vps

I am very new to server I had two domains in one Virtual Private  server I did redirect through CPANEL its working fine .I  redirect my website URL [enter link description here](http://www.exampleone.com) to [enter link description here](http://www.exampleone.com) But my i want to user [enter link description here](http://www.exampleone.com) only visible to me how can i visible only to me please any one help me how to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you have static IP addresses, then you can configure .htaccess file to allow the access to your website from certain IP addresses only. Following threads might help you.

[Only allow certain IP addresses to access site with mod_rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145978/only-allow-certain-ip-addresses-to-access-site-with-mod-rewrite)

[Deny all, allow only one IP through htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400154/deny-all-allow-only-one-ip-through-htaccess)

As an alternative, you can make the destination website as password protected directory. Thus, only you'll be allowed to access the website.