# Adding a range of allowed IP addresses to htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, range, whitelist

I need to add IP addresses to my .htaccess to allow access as shown in this question.

[Only allow certain IP addresses to access site with mod_rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145978/only-allow-certain-ip-addresses-to-access-site-with-mod-rewrite)

But I need to be able to add them as a range as I have some that span a great range and typing them out individually will take way too long. is there a way to express a range which will work with this format?

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^XXX\.XXX\.XXX\.XXX
```

Comment: Only by leaving of segments at the right, I suppose, because this is essentially string comparison. If you don’t need an actual rewrite to somewhere else, but just to allow or deny access, then check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042399/htaccess-access-to-file-by-ip-range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is !

If you want to block a range of IPs then you can leave off the last octet of the IP address, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123
```

and you can shorten that even further if needed:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123
```

So for example, using the first option, you would be blocking the IP range of 123.123.123.**1** - 123.123.123.**255**. So it covers the entire range.

This can also be achieved using the `deny from` rule in `.htaccess`.

Comment: Thanks, thats perfect